# Html.RenderAction from another controller with passed parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

I'm having 2 models: **Player** and **PlayerAchievement**

```
 public class Player
 {
    [Required]
    public String clubName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String position { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string placeOfBirth { get; set; }
    //TODO: Remember to change variable name
    [Required]
    public double weight { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double height { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String imageLink { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Boolean status { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerAchievement
{
    [Key]        
    public String playerID { get; set; }               
    [Required]
    public String achievementName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int number { get; set; }
}
```

The **Player** has the **Details** view which show the detail information of player. I want to render **ShowPlayerAchievement** view in there. However, the **ShowPlayerAchievement** Action is in **PlayerAchievement** Controller

```
public ActionResult ShowAchievementsList(String playerID)
{
   return View(_repository.GetPlayerAchievementsByPlayerID(playerID));
}
```

As you see above, the method requires the **playerID** of the player, so I tried this code of **@Html.RenderAction** in Details.cshtml of **Player** to see if it works, but it didn't.

```
@Html.RenderAction("ShowAchievementsList", "PlayerAchievement", new { playerID = Model.id })
```

### So to summarize, how can I call the **ShowAchievementList** action from **PlayerAchievement** controller with **playerID** parameter from the Player ?

**UPDATE**
this code doesn't show error
     @Html.Action("ShowAchievementsList", "PlayerAchievement", new { playerID = Model.id });

But I got an NullRefferenceException in constructor of PlayerAchievementRepository class.

public class PlayerAchievementRepository : IPlayerAchievementRepository
    {

```
    public List<PlayerAchievement> allPlayerAchievements;
    private XDocument playerAchievementData;

    public PlayerAchievementRepository()
    {
        allPlayerAchievements = new List<PlayerAchievement>();

        playerAchievementData = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/player_management.xml"));
//Error show here
        var playerAchievements = from playerAchievement in playerAchievementData.Descendants("player_achievement")                                     
                      select new PlayerAchievement((int) playerAchievement.Element("number"), playerAchievement.Element("playerID").Value, 
                          playerAchievement.Element("achievementName").Value);                allPlayerAchievements.AddRange(playerAchievements.ToList<PlayerAchievement>());
//other logic codes...

    }
```

in player_management.xml

```
<player_achievement>
        <number>3</number>
        <playerId>01</playerId>
        <achievementName>European Cup</achievementName>
</player_achievement>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these two syntaxes:

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("ShowAchievementsList", "PlayerAchievement", new { playerID = Model.id });}
```

or

```
 @Html.Action("ShowAchievementsList", "PlayerAchievement", new { playerID = Model.id });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
@{
@Html.RenderAction("ShowAchievementsList", "PlayerAchievement", new { playerID = Model.id })
}
```